# How do I sign out of all devices currently using my Apple ID?

Tags: apple-id, password

I have an ex that is using my Apple ID, and I want to get him off my account. I have changed my password, but as he was already signed in, it appears that he is still using my account.

I remember once in the past when I changed my password, I was given the option to sign out of all devices currently using that Apple ID, but that option seems to have disappeared.

Comment: Changing your password *should* sign out your Apple ID, but I have no citable reference for this.

Comment: I agree with @grgarside. Without researching how Apple handles authentication, typically an account user (any device signed into your Apple ID) would access servers using the *credentials provided originally*. It would not know the new password and hence further use would be impossible.

Answer (score 5):

Go to https://www.icloud.com/#settings & hit "Sign out of all browsers' then change your password again.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.icloud.com/#settings

Using this I have sign out from all the browsers and simultaneously in the same browser I was signed in https://appleid.apple.com/account/manage here, but this sign out does not work, because still I was able to access my account on different tab. Not sure for the iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Go to itunes official site
You will see the bag icon on the top right corner

> press account (log in necessary) 
>   edit apple ID (you will be asked to re-enter your password)
>   click devices (you will have to answer 2 of your security questions)
>   see all the devices that are using your apple ID
>   click the remove maked red below the device

If you forgot the answers to the security questions, you can reset it by sending a verification through email. Re-answer your security questions then go through the process again.

I used my iPhone6 in doing this so using other devices might have a different format or placement of the icons.